# Exchange 2010 to 2016 Public Folder

Tags: exchange, migration

PUBLIC FOLDER MIGRATION stage.

Error at assigning new public folder to all users following this guide;-

https://supertekboy.com/2016/03/11/exchange-2016-public-folder-migration-part-2/

Have tested public folder using a test user account - all working.

Now trying to assign to all users this command;-

```
Get-Mailbox -PublicFolder | Set-Mailbox -PublicFolder -IsExcludedFromServingHierarchy $false
```

I get the following error message;-

> This command completed successfully but no settings of
>   'ad.xnxnxnxnxnx.xx/users/mailbox1' have been modified.

I test public folders with another account which hasn't manually assigned and they can't access public folders.

I'm now stuck with a potential 200 users Monday morning who can't access Public Folders.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Have you run the following commands to complete the migration?
On the legacy Exchange server, run the following command to indicate that the public folder migration is complete:

```
Set-OrganizationConfig -PublicFolderMigrationComplete:$true
```

After you've verified that the migration is complete, on the Exchange 2016 server, run the following command:

```
Set-OrganizationConfig -PublicFoldersEnabled Local
```

If run but still cannot access, please wait for few days and check again.